# rdd.filter() is not working properly for spark-2.0.1

Tags: filter, pyspark

I want to filter out the element of an `RDD` following a string value as in:

```
est_rdd = est_rdd.filter(lambda kv: kv[0] !=name_to_filter )
```

However, I see the filtered element is still in `est_rdd`. In that case I need to repartition for the next step to clear. But it is a time-consuming operation. How should I avoid repartitioning? Any help?

Comment: can you provide a small example of your rdd? It seems strange that your filter operation does not work properly

Comment: Thanks for your response. The previous step was a flat_map operation that contains [filename, value1, value2] and I am using the filename as key. It is actually matching but if I do not repartition it retains the matched element in the rdd. I have tested as local mode.

Comment: Even I seem to be facing this issue. My string comparison `filter` on `DF` pushes through some incorrect results (spark 2.3.0). Has this something to do with partitioning or the lineage of the rdd? What did you do?

Comment: @void, I did this `est_rdd = est_rdd.filter(lambda kv: kv[0] !=name_to_filter ) // est_rdd = est_rdd.repartition(npartitions)` but remember it is a costly operation

Comment: How is repartitioning helping you filter out incorrect result? I did not get that part.

Answer (score 0):

Spark has been tested carefully so I would discard the possibility of Spark not doing its job.

Check that the expected string `name_to_filter` matches **exactly** with the string in the key. Sometimes there are subtle differences that you ignore

Comment: Hi Luis, I have tested local mode and it is actually matching but retains the matched one.

Comment: I tested several times for spark 2.0.1 built from source code version. Direct filtering is somewhat problematic for sure in my case. However it works well without repartitioning, after zipwithindex.......and using index range as,                            filtered_rdd = temprdd.filter(lambda (key, index): key in range(start, end+1))